# STM32F4 (Nucleo) SPI line doesn't transmit

Tags: arm, nucleo, coocox

I can't seem to get my SPI line to work. It doesn't want to transmit at all although it does generate a clock signal on sck pin.

The Clock signal has a frequency of 62 kHz, the MOSI and MISO pins remain high indefinitely. I've built the code according to how the library defines it should be used, although I'm not sure if my transmit function is incorrect. I've also done error and state checks, the error checks come back saying there are no errors and the state says that the SPI bus is ready.
Here's my code:

```
//*****************************************************************************
//
//! \file main.c
//! \brief main application
//! \version 1.0.0.0
//! \date $Creat_time$
//! \author $Creat_author$
//! \copy
//!
//! Copyright (c) 2014 CooCox.  All rights reserved.
//
//! \addtogroup project
//! @{
//! \addtogroup main
//! @{
//*****************************************************************************
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

int main(void)
{
//Initialize Variables
//*****************************************************************************
uint32_t x;
uint32_t x1;
//Variables to check the state of the SPI bus.
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t1;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t2;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t3;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t4;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t5;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t6;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t7;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t8;
HAL_SPI_StateTypeDef t9;
uint8_t message = 0xA4;
//*****************************************************************************


//(1)Declare a SPI_HandleTypeDef handle structure, for example: SPI_HandleTypeDef  hspi;
//*****************************************************************************
SPI_HandleTypeDef  SPIinit;
SPIinit.Instance = SPI1;
t1=  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);
//*****************************************************************************



//(2)Initialize the SPI low level resources by implementing the HAL_SPI_MspInit ()API:
//*****************************************************************************
HAL_SPI_MspInit(&SPIinit);
t2=  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);
//*****************************************************************************




// (3) Enable the SPIx interface clock
//*****************************************************************************
__HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();
t3 =  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);
//*****************************************************************************


// (4) SPI pins configuration
//(4.a) Enable the clock for the SPI GPIOs
//*****************************************************************************
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
//*****************************************************************************


//(4.b) Configure these SPI pins as alternate function push-pull
//*****************************************************************************

//Configure the SPI SCK,MISO & MOSI pins

GPIO_InitTypeDef NSS;

NSS.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_4;
NSS.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
NSS.Pull      = GPIO_PULLUP;
NSS.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
NSS.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;


//HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &NSS);


GPIO_InitTypeDef SCK;

SCK.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_3;
SCK.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
SCK.Pull      = GPIO_PULLUP;
SCK.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
SCK.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &SCK);


GPIO_InitTypeDef MISO;

MISO.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_4;
MISO.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
MISO.Pull      = GPIO_PULLUP;
MISO.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
MISO.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &MISO);


GPIO_InitTypeDef MOSI;

MOSI.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_5;
MOSI.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
MOSI.Pull      = GPIO_PULLUP;
MOSI.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
MOSI.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &MOSI);

//Configure the SPI NSS pin

//*****************************************************************************


//(5) Program the Mode, Direction , Data size, Baudrate Prescaler, NSS management, Clock polarity and phase, FirstBit and CRC configuration in the hspi Init structure
//*****************************************************************************

SPI_InitTypeDef SPItest;

SPItest.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
SPItest.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE;
SPItest.DataSize =  SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
SPItest.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
SPItest.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
SPItest.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
SPItest.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
SPItest.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE ;
SPItest.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
SPItest.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;

t4=  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);
//*****************************************************************************

//(6) Initialize the SPI registers by calling the HAL_SPI_Init() API:
//*****************************************************************************
HAL_SPI_Init(&SPIinit);
t5=  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);
//*****************************************************************************

__HAL_SPI_ENABLE(&SPIinit);


while(1)

 {

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    //t6=  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);
    //x1 = HAL_SPI_GetError(&SPIinit);

    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&SPIinit, &message, 7, 0x01);

//  t8=  HAL_SPI_GetState(&SPIinit);

//  x = HAL_SPI_GetError(&SPIinit);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4,GPIO_PIN_SET);
 }
}

    //  SPI STATE CHECK
// HAL_SPI_STATE_RESET      = 0x00,  /*!< SPI not yet initialized or disabled                */
// HAL_SPI_STATE_READY      = 0x01,  /*!< SPI initialized and ready for use                  */
// HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY       = 0x02,  /*!< SPI process is ongoing                             */
// HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_TX    = 0x12,  /*!< Data Transmission process is ongoing               */
// HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_RX    = 0x22,  /*!< Data Reception process is ongoing                  */
// HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_TX_RX = 0x32,  /*!< Data Transmission and Reception process is ongoing */
// HAL_SPI_STATE_ERROR      = 0x03   /*!< SPI error state                                    */

//  SPI ERROR CHECK
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_NONE         ((uint32_t)0x00000000)   /*!< No error             */
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_MODF         ((uint32_t)0x00000001)   /*!< MODF error           */
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_CRC          ((uint32_t)0x00000002)   /*!< CRC error            */
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_OVR          ((uint32_t)0x00000004)   /*!< OVR error            */
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_FRE          ((uint32_t)0x00000008)   /*!< FRE error            */
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_DMA          ((uint32_t)0x00000010)   /*!< DMA transfer error   */
//#define HAL_SPI_ERROR_FLAG         ((uint32_t)0x00000010)   /*!< Flag: RXNE,TXE, BSY  */
```

I've tried both GPIOA and GPIOB alternate functions..Any help will really be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code, it seems that you don't actually set up your SPI instance. You do not set up the `SPI_InitTypeDef` of your `SPI_HandleTypeDef`.  Replace your `SPItest` by `SPIinit.Init`:

```
//SPI_InitTypeDef SPItest;

SPIinit.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
SPIinit.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE;
SPIinit.Init.DataSize =  SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
SPIinit.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
SPIinit.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
SPIinit.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
SPIinit.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
SPIinit.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE ;
SPIinit.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
SPIinit.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;

HAL_SPI_Init(&SPIinit);
```